# How do I log in when my OpenID provider is down or offline?

Tags: support, login, openid

When I registered with Stack Overflow 18 months ago, I used myOpenID as my login preference. That service seems to be down at the moment (I have since this discovered that this is a common problem), so I am struggling to get logged in.

When I requested account recovery details, the email message simply confirmed my credentials at myOpenID, without providing any alternative options.

I have created a separate account with Stack Exchange to make this post, but I would like to access my other account. I investigated merging this new account with the inaccessible one, but it seems that this is impossible in the current scenario.

How can I get logged in while the myOpenID service is down?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OpenID is now deprecated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "correct" solution is to add an alternate OpenID provider to your account when you can access it. If you go to your profile you'll see a "my logins" link (#1 in the image below). Click that and you'll see something like the following dialog:

[image: manage logins]

<sup>(Obviously yours will only have one OpenID).</sup>

Click on the "add more logins..." link (#2 in the image above) and add an ID from another provider—Facebook, Stack Exchange themselves, etc.

Then the next time myOpenID is down, you can use one this to access your account.

However, in your current situation as myOpenID is down, you can't do that. So you have done the right thing by creating a second account with a different OpenID provider. The next step is to [get the two accounts merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist). If you used the same e-mail address on both, that will make it easier for the moderators to confirm that you own both accounts. You may have to give hints as to the OpenID used as well, but that will depend on who's doing the merging.

This will add the new OpenID to your existing account, putting you in the same position as if you'd added it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Now that you've created another account, you can flag one of your posts and ask a moderator to merge your accounts [as described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist).

Once the accounts are merged, you can login with either of the OpenIDs that you've used on both the accounts.

Personally, I have added 3 services to the My Logins section of my profile...

[image: My Logins]

... so that nothing comes in my way of my Stack Exchange addiction.